# selenium throws "option element is not in a select" exception

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I am writing selenium automation against an Angular 2 application.  In the application, there is a field the user can type in to filter a dropdown that appears as soon as they start typing.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<input> /* this is where the user starts typing */
<datalist>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    ...
</datalist>
```

I am getting the input element and entering partial text:

```
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='inputField']"));
inputField.clear();
inputField.sendKeys(partialText);
```

This is working as expected.  The list drops down and is filtered appropriately.  Next I find the element containing the option I want:

```
WebElement option =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//datalist/option[contains(text(), '" + myOption + "')]"));
```

That call is successful.  But when I try to click() on it, I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: option element is not in a select
```

I tried using Actions and Robot, but I ran into two problems:
  1) As soon as I tried to press the down arrow, the dropdown closed, and 2) I don't know how, even if I could somehow select an option, I could get the text to see if I had the right option selected.

How can I select an option?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the link to the page?

Comment: @Grasshopper I can't share a link to the page as it's a proprietary app

Comment: By any chance have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the option element using `javascriptExecutor`.Look at below example.

```
WebElement elementToSelect =
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//datalist/option[contains(text(), '" + myOption + "')]")); 
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToSelect);
```

Comment: Good idea, and one I should have thought of myself, but it doesn't work - it collapses the dropdown just like pressing a key with Robot or Actions.